# Convert string with escaped characters and ASCII values into HEX

Tags: javascript, python, string

I have the following string which contains escaped HEX values and ASCII characters

```
"\01B\2E\00   k\00"
```

A backslash means that the next two characters are HEX values, everything else in the  string is ASCII

The goal is to convert the entire string into all HEX values

end result:

```
"\01\42\2E\00\20\20\20\6B\00"
```

*::edit::*

I had tried the following:

```
s = "\01B\2E\00   k\00"
r = [ ]

for x in s:
    r.append(x.encode("hex"))

print r
```

the problem was the values (ex:  \1E ) were being interpreted as \x01 and E

Then i ran into the following question [online](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-April/061025.html) came to post an update, and realized my question was already answered.

Thanks

Comment: Which language's string is that exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the answers below, I just found out i could use raw characters in python, I was using python and javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Python string that contains escaped hex values and ascii characters.

```
>>> s = r"\01B\2E\00   k\00"
>>> s
'\\01B\\2E\\00   k\\00'
>>> print(s)
\01B\2E\00   k\00
```

First we decode with the `string-escape` codec to convert the escaped hex values into the character representation. In order to use `string-escape` with hexadecimal values, we need to use `\x` for the escape indicator rather than just `\` (which implies octal values iirc)

```
>>> escaped = s.replace('\\', '\\x').decode('string-escape')
>>> escaped
'\x01B.\x00   k\x00'
>>> print escaped
B.   k
```

Some of our characters are not printable. But the result is that all our characters are hex values/characters.

If you want to convert all the characters in the **escaped hex representation**, however, you will need to convert explicitly into hex values:

```
>>> h = ''.join('\\' + char.encode('hex') for char in escaped)
>>> h
'\\01\\42\\2e\\00\\20\\20\\20\\6b\\00'
>>> print h
\01\42\2e\00\20\20\20\6b\00
```

Note that bytes-to-bytes encoding is deprecated in Python3. You would instead use the [`binascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) `.hexlify` and `.unhexlify` methods.

Comment: Is this solution character-encoding agnostic, i.e. are `.decode('string-escape)'` and `.encode('hex')` symmetric to each other under all circumstances?

Comment: @Tomalak I believe so. `string-escape` converts to byte representation independent of character encoding, and `.encode` re-escapes the bytes, again independent of character encoding.

Comment: However, the `hex` encoding is deprecated in Python3. Added a note.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.split()` to tokenize the string in Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = r"\01B\2E\00   k\00"
>>> L = re.split(r'((?:\\{hex}{hex})+)'.format(hex='[0-9a-fA-F]'), data)
>>> L
['', '\\01', 'B', '\\2E\\00', '   k', '\\00', '']
>>> L[::2] = [''.join('\\' + c.encode('hex') for c in s) for s in L[::2]]
>>> print ''.join(L)
\01\42\2E\00\20\20\20\6b\00
```